# What is the average distance $\langle r \rangle$ of a particle in an ideal gas in a potential from the origin?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas

I have an ideal gas in three dimensions of N identical particles with mass $m$ in a potential $u(\textbf{q})= \alpha ||\textbf{q}||,$ where $\alpha>0.$ The Hamiltonian is
$$
H(q^N, p^N) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{\textbf{p}^2_i}{2 m} + \sum_{i=1}^N u(\textbf{q}_i).
$$
The particles are not interacting with each other and the system is in contact with a heat reservoir of temperature $T$.

I'd like to calculate the average distance $\langle r\rangle$ of the particles from the origin.

If I had to calculate the average energy, this would just be
$$
\langle H\rangle = \int dq^Ndp^N \rho(q^N, p^N)  H(q^N, p^N).
$$
Here we have one scalar value for a microstate $(q^N, p^N)$. How can I do do this for the average distance to the origin?

This is what I tried so far:
Realize that there is no interaction between the particles so just consider one particle. The partition function for one particle is
$$
Z(\beta)=
\int_{\mathbb{R}^6} d^3qd^3p\quad e^{-\beta\frac{\textbf{p}^2}{2 m} - \beta \alpha |\textbf{q}| }\\ 
=
\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3p \, e^{-\beta\frac{\textbf{p}^2}{2 m} }\right)\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3q \, e^{-\beta \alpha |\textbf{q}| }\right)\\ 
=
\left(4\pi\int_0^{\infty}dr_p\, r^2_p \, e^{-\beta\frac{r_p^2}{2 m} }\right)\left(4\pi\int_0^{\infty}dr_q\, r^2_q \, e^{-\beta \alpha r_q }\right)\\
=
\left(4\pi \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}\left(\frac{2m}{\beta}\right)^{3/2}\right)\left(4\pi 2\left(\frac{1}{\beta\alpha}\right)^{3}\right)\\
=
\left(\frac{2^9 m^3 \pi^5}{\beta^9 \alpha^6}\right)^{1/2}.
$$
Then the average distance to the origin is given by
$$
\langle r\rangle=
\frac{1}{Z}\int_{\mathbb{R}^6} d^3qd^3p\quad e^{-\beta\frac{\textbf{p}^2}{2 m} - \beta \alpha |\textbf{q}| } |\textbf{q}|\\ 
=
\frac{1}{Z}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3p \, e^{-\beta\frac{\textbf{p}^2}{2 m} }\right)\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3q \, e^{-\beta \alpha |\textbf{q}| }|\textbf{q}|\right)\\ 
=
\frac{1}{Z}\left(4\pi \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}\left(\frac{2m}{\beta}\right)^{3/2}\right)\left(4\pi 6\left(\frac{1}{\beta\alpha}\right)^{4}\right)\\
=\frac{3}{\alpha \beta}.
$$
This is then also the average distance to the origin for all particles. Is my definition of $\langle r\rangle$ the right one?

Answer (score 3):

Your calculations look fine, but notice that you could've calculated $\langle r \rangle$ directly from the partition function since
$$\langle r \rangle=-\frac{1}{\beta}\frac{\partial \log Z}{\partial \alpha}.$$ This agrees with your result as $$\log Z \propto -3\log\alpha$$ (the $\alpha$-independent terms can be ignored), and so $$-\frac{1}{\beta}\frac{\partial \log Z}{\partial \alpha}=\frac{3}{\beta\alpha}.$$

Interestingly, for $V(r)=\alpha r^n$ we have $$\log Z \propto-\frac{3}{n}\log\alpha$$ (you can figure this out by doing the substitution $r\to r/\alpha^{1/n}$ in the radial integral ) and so $$\langle r \rangle=\frac{3}{n\alpha}kT.$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the answer looks correct.
$$
Z_1 = \int d^3\mathbf{p} d^3\mathbf{q}e^{-\beta\frac{\mathbf{p}^2}{2m}-\beta u(\mathbf{q})}=
\int d^3\mathbf{p} e^{-\beta\frac{\mathbf{p}^2}{2m}} \int d^3\mathbf{q}e^{-\beta u(\mathbf{q})}
$$
$$
\langle |\mathbf{q}|\rangle = \frac{1}{Z_1}\int d^3\mathbf{p} d^3\mathbf{q}|\mathbf{q}|e^{-\beta\frac{\mathbf{p}^2}{2m}-\beta u(\mathbf{q})}=\frac{1}{Z_1}
\int d^3\mathbf{p} e^{-\beta\frac{\mathbf{p}^2}{2m}} \int d^3\mathbf{q}|\mathbf{q}|e^{-\beta u(\mathbf{q})}=\\
\frac{\int d^3\mathbf{q}|\mathbf{q}|e^{-\beta u(\mathbf{q})}}{\int d^3\mathbf{q}e^{-\beta u(\mathbf{q})}}=
\frac{\int d^3\mathbf{q}|\mathbf{q}|e^{-\beta \alpha |\mathbf{q}|}}{\int d^3\mathbf{q}e^{-\beta \alpha |\mathbf{q}|}}=
\frac{\int_0^{+\infty}dq q^3e^{-\beta \alpha q}}{\int_0^{+\infty} dq q^2e^{-\beta \alpha q}}=
\frac{\frac{\Gamma(4)}{(\beta\alpha)^4}}{\frac{\Gamma(3)}{(\beta\alpha)^3}}=
\frac{3!}{2!}\frac{1}{\beta\alpha}=\frac{3}{\beta\alpha},
$$
where $\Gamma(x)=\int_0^{+\infty}t^{x-1}e^{-x}dt$ is the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) (which may be a shorter but a bit fancier way to evaluate this integral - if not, use integration by parts.)

Answer (score 1):

> ...The Hamiltonian is
> $$
> H(q^N, p^N) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{\textbf{p}^2_i}{2 m} + \sum_{i=1}^N u(\textbf{q}_i).
> $$
> The particles are not interacting with each other and the system is in contact with a heat reservoir of temperature $T$.

> ...
> If I had to calculate the average energy, this would just be
> $$
> \langle H\rangle = \int dq^Ndp^N \rho(q^N, p^N)  H(q^N, p^N).
> $$

> How can I do do this for the average distance to the origin?

For *any* function $f(\mathbf{q},\mathbf{p})$ that you want to average, where $\mathbf{q}=(\vec q_1, \ldots, \vec q_N)$ and similarly for $\mathbf{p}$, regardless of if it is the Hamiltonian, or the distance to the origin, or whatever, you always do it like:
$$
\langle f\rangle = \int d^Nq d^Np \rho(\mathbf{q},\mathbf{p})f(\mathbf{q},\mathbf{p})
$$

You have already realized that when there is no interaction you can work with an effective single-particle $\rho_1(\vec q_1,\vec p_1)$, but you might want to see how this works out in more detail.

If you want to average using the *full* Hamiltonian, then you should note that you are averaging in two ways, one way is using the distribution $\rho$ and the other is averaging "by hand" over all the $N$ particles. In this "full" case you are interested in averaging a function $g$, where
$$
g = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N|\vec q_i|\;.
$$

Classically, the "full" probability density in phase space is:
$$
\rho(\vec q_1,\ldots, \vec p_N) = \frac{1}{N!h^{(3N)}}\frac{1}{Z_N}e^{-\beta H(\vec q_1,\ldots,\vec p_N)}\;,
$$
where
$$
Z_N = \frac{1}{h^{(3N)} N!}\int d^3q_1\ldots d^3p_N e^{-\beta H}\;.
$$
(Citation: R. Kubo "Principles of Statistical Mechanics," at equations 1.70a and 1.71a.)

And, when the Hamiltonian is non-interacting, we can factor $Z$ and $\rho$. For example, in the non-interacting case $Z_N=\left(Z_1\right)^N/N!$, where $Z_1$ is the single-particle partition function.

The average of the function of interest is:
$$
\langle g\rangle = \frac{1}{h^{3N}Z_1^N}\frac{1}{N}\int d^3q_1d^3p_1\ldots d^3q_N d^3p_N \left(|\vec q_1|+|q_2|+\ldots + |q_N|\right)e^{-\beta \left(\frac{\vec p_1^2}{2m} + u(|\vec q_1|)\right)}\ldots
e^{-\beta \left(\frac{\vec p_N^2}{2m} + u(|\vec q_N|)\right)}
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{h^3Z_1}\int d^3 q_1 d^3 p_1 |\vec q_1|e^{-\beta \left(\frac{\vec p_1^2}{2m} + u(|\vec q_1|)\right)}
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{\int d^3q_1 e^{-\beta u(|\vec q_1|)}}\int d^3 q_1 |\vec q_1|e^{-\beta u(|\vec q_1|)}
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{\int dr r^2 e^{-\beta u(r)}}\int dr r^3e^{-\beta u(r)}
$$

> I have an ideal gas in three dimensions of N identical particles with mass $m$ in a potential $u(\textbf{q})= \alpha ||\textbf{q}||,$ where $\alpha>0.$

So, in your case, for this specific potential, we have:
$$
\langle g \rangle 
=\frac{1}{\int dr r^2 e^{-\beta\alpha r}}\int dr r^3e^{-\beta\alpha r}
$$
$$
=\frac{-\frac{\partial^3}{\partial (\alpha\beta)^3}(\alpha\beta)^{-1}}{\frac{\partial^2}{\partial (\alpha\beta)^2}(\alpha\beta)^{-1}}
$$
$$
=\frac{3}{\alpha\beta}\;.
$$